# Name must be a namespace name

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I'm going through the documentation on building a UWP winrt application but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be set up properly.

I create a new coreapp which shows 56 errors, starting with "name must be a namespace name" for 'winrt' and 'Windows'.

How do I actually get the winrt namespace usable in my project?

Per the documentation I've installed Universal Windows Platform C++ (v143) in Visual Studio, and enabled Developer mode option in Windows. The NuGet Package Manager for the project shows Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT version 2.0.230225.1 is installed.

Expected to have usable header files in the project, but don't.

*pch.h*

```
#pragma once
#include <windows.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Core.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Composition.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Input.h>
```

--

E1696   cannot open source file "winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h"
...

Comment: What ``#include`` statements have you added to your project? C++/WinRT projections are C++, so you have to add the right headers to your project. For example see [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/blob/main/d3d11game_uwp_cppwinrt_dr/pch.h#L38).

Comment: Just the default ones in the core app: 'windows.h', then some winrt ones which can't be opened. I included the ones from your example, but it didn't help make the winrt headers accessible.

Comment: The `winrt` namespace comes from the `#include <winrt/...>` headers, so if they can't be found, then naturally the namespace won't be defined. Look at the Output window. Did the cppwinrt.exe program run as part of the build process? Where did it put its output? Did you add that directory to your INCLUDE path?

Comment: Naturally. I didn't see anything about ccpwinrt.exe being run as part of the build process, but I manually found a "Generated Files" directory in the project root. Adding that as an include directory resolved the errors. Thanks.

Comment: `E1696` is an IntelliSense error, not a compiler error. You'll get those whenever you create a new C++/WinRT project, as the projection headers are generated on-the-fly during a build. The IntelliSense errors go away once you build the project at least once.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is explained in the C++/WinRT [troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/troubleshooting#symptoms-and-remedies) guide:

> | Symptom | Remedy |
> | --- | --- |
> | In a C++/WinRT project in Visual Studio, IntelliSense produces an error of the form *"error E1696: cannot open source file"*. | Compile your newly created project at least once. Then right-click in the source code editor > **Rescan** > **Rescan File**. That will resolve all IntelliSense errors, including E1696. |

The reason for this is that the projection header files are referenced from the wizard-generated source code, but haven't been generated yet. They get generated as needed by the *cppwinrt.exe* tool as part of the build process.

Comment: As I said above, it wasn't so simple. I had to manually dig up the files and include them. I swear I have more problems with visual studio than anything.